# Proper "container" for data display/modification

Tags: c#, .net, autocad

I'm creating a windows form where a user will run a command in Autocad, it will prompt them to select an object(specifically 3d polylines).  A 3d polyline can have a very wide range of Vertex's.  I want each Vertex to be on/create it's own row.  Each row having 5 columns(properties of each Vertex).

What's the proper container to use for this?  I am expecting the user to be able to modify(change elevation for example) each and every property in each vertex.   Along with actually deleting any vertices that they want to.

Table Layout Panel? Regular Panel?  Here's the code of me "getting" the vertices:

```
        using (AcDb.Transaction oTr = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
        {
            AcDb.ObjectIdCollection ids = new AcDb.ObjectIdCollection();

            AcEd.PromptEntityOptions options = new AcEd.PromptEntityOptions("\nSelect a 3DPolyline:");
            options.SetRejectMessage("That is not select a 3DPolyline" + "\n");
            options.AddAllowedClass(typeof(AcDb.Polyline3d), true);
            AcEd.PromptEntityResult result = ed.GetEntity(options);

            if (result.Status != AcEd.PromptStatus.OK) return;

            AcDb.Polyline3d oEnt = oTr.GetObject(result.ObjectId, AcDb.OpenMode.ForRead) as AcDb.Polyline3d;


            foreach (AcDb.ObjectId oVtId in oEnt)
            {
                AcDb.PolylineVertex3d oVt = oTr.GetObject(oVtId, AcDb.OpenMode.ForRead) as AcDb.PolylineVertex3d;
                //now to populate...something
```

Comment: possibly a datagrid? should allow you to view a collection of vertex objects and modify directly (with included before/after edit events)... deleting isn't as obvious (select row, press delete on keyboard), so maybe throw in a toolbar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A DataTable would make sense when gathering the data.

```
using (var trans = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
{
    var options = new PromptEntityOptions("\nSelect a 3DPolyline:");
    options.SetRejectMessage("That is not select a 3DPolyline" + "\n");
    options.AddAllowedClass(typeof(Polyline3d), true);
    var result = ed.GetEntity(options);

    if (result.Status != PromptStatus.OK)
        return;

    var poly = (Polyline3d)trans.GetObject(result.ObjectId, OpenMode.ForRead);
    var vertexClass = RXClass.GetClass(typeof(PolylineVertex3d));

    var vertexTable = new System.Data.DataTable("Vertices");
    vertexTable.Columns.Add("HandleId", typeof(long));
    vertexTable.Columns.Add("PositionX", typeof(double));
    vertexTable.Columns.Add("PositionY", typeof(double));
    vertexTable.Columns.Add("PositionZ", typeof(double));

    foreach (ObjectId vertexId in poly)
    {
        if (!vertexId.ObjectClass.IsDerivedFrom(vertexClass))
            continue;

        var vertex = (PolylineVertex3d)trans.GetObject(vertexId, OpenMode.ForRead);
        vertexTable.Rows.Add(vertex.Handle.Value, vertex.Position.X, vertex.Position.Y, vertex.Position.Z);
    }

    trans.Commit();
}
```

Once you've got your vertex data in a table you can bind it to visual controls very easily.

Comment: Am I wrong in assuming that this would have been editing the data "live"?  I have it populating the form, but changing anything (z value for example) doesn't do anything once I've closed the form.  Do I need to do something specific on form close?

Comment: Depending on your application requirements, you'll need to address what happens when data changes.  If you simply want the changes on the form to be applied to the objects, using the current logic you'd have to re-obtain them (you can get ObjectID from Handle) to edit them, and then commit a new transaction.

Comment: Alternately (and probably better in your case) would be to leave the DBObjects and transaction open while the form is shown, and then update the data once it closes.  You'll have to create a method that sets the updated table values to the objects you have open.

Comment: I guess I don't even see where the transaction is closing, I've tried moving the "trans.Commit(); around, right now it's completely removed and nothing different happens.  Regardless...basically I should create a new method that reads the datagrid and translate that back into "writing" to the db.

Comment: Transaction implements IDisposable, so when the using statement is exited, the Transaction closes.  Committing the transaction is going to be required if you want changes to the DBObjects to persist.  Yes, you will need a method to write the changes on the grid back to the AutoCAD DbObjects

Comment: I'll go from there, thank you for all your help sir.  Much appreciated.